# bbCode, adding smileys?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I'm trying to add smileys to my website (bbCodes) but I can't figure out how to do it. I have all the smileys triggerwords and outputs in my database to make it easier to remove/add smileys.

This bit of code below does nothing... I do not get an error and it doesn't replace for example :happy: with the image happy.png

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include('/var/www/files/connect.php');
$SmileysQ = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM smileys");
$SmileysQ->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($Smileys = $SmileysQ->fetch()) {
$text = preg_replace ('/\''.$Smileys['trigger'].'/is', '<img src="images/smileys/'.$Smileys['output'].'.png" height="15" width="15" />', $text);
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an unintended `'` mark in the first argument of the preg_replace causing it to fail as it was searching for `':happy:` not `:happy:`

The proper replace would more likely be:

```
$text = preg_replace ('/'.$Smileys['trigger'].'/is', '<img src="images/smileys/'.$Smileys['output'].'.png" height="15" width="15" />', $text);
```

example:

```
$text = ":happy: this is a test!";
$code = ":happy:";
$text = preg_replace ('/'.$code.'/is', '<img src="images/smileys/happy.png" height="15" width="15" />', $text);
print $text;
/*
outputs: <img src="images/smileys/happy.png" height="15" width="15" /> this is a test!
the extra ' gave me: :happy: this is a test!
*/
```